# Radius of Electric Field Between Large Plate and Point

Tags: electric-fields

[image]

Observe this little diagram. Here is what I don't understand: the electric field *does not* dissipate as we move from point C to D to E. Why? By the inverse squared law, shouldn't the electric field strength decrease as the measurement points move away from the large plate? I simply do not understand how the electric field strength is constant.

EDIT: A picture of the vectors.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The electric field would be constant if  the configuration of the charge on the right was an infinite sheet or plane of charge, or where the dimensions of the  sheet vertically and into the page were much greater than the distance from the sheet to point C or D.  Under those conditions, the field would have constant magnitude of

$$E=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon}$$

Where $\sigma$ is the charge density in coulombs/meter$^2$ and $\epsilon$ is the electrical permittivity of the space in farads/meter (8.85 x 10$^{-12}$ for free space or air).

The reason the field does not follow the inverse square law is that the field at C and D is the vector sum of the field contributions of all of charges extending in all directions on the sheet, and not just one charge.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134068/discussion-on-answer-by-bob-d-radius-of-electric-field-between-large-plate-and-p).